# English dictionary in Libreoffice

Tags: 11.10, libreoffice, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a LibreOffice Dictionary (Spelling Check, Thesaurus…)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72099/how-to-install-a-libreoffice-dictionary-spelling-check-thesaurus)

Currently, spell check doesn't work when 'English (UK)' is selected in Tools > Language.

It only works with the US variant.

Strangely, despite giving the UK variant option in Tools > Language, Under Tools > Option > Language, there is no blue tick indicating the dictionary is installed.

I've tried finding an english UK/GB dictionary extension with no luck.

Can anyone suggest how to find and install a English (GB) dictionary and work with spellchecker?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72099/how-to-install-a-libreoffice-dictionary-spelling-check-thesaurus).

Comment: Thank you! Although it didn't fix my problem. I've fixed it now however, I had to install dict-en.oxt from the Open Office to provide the UK english dictionary.

Comment: Can you post the steps that you used to solve your issue on the other question? They are very similar in content and that might help other ppl solving their issues!

Comment: Here is how to fix it:
Basically, the Libreoffice Ubuntu gets shipped with only comes with the american dictionary.

1) To get all English variants go to:
http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/dict-en-fixed

2) Download dict-en.oxt

3) Go to extension manager in Libreoffice, and install dict-en.oxt

4) Go to Tools > Options > Language Settings > Language and change the 'Default languages for documents' to English (UK) (or whatever variant)

[Check that the english variant you want to use has a blue tick, indicating the correct dictionary is installed]