# why spelling checker and grammer checkers are not there in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

Why the libreOffice dose not detect any wrong words or wrong grammar, even I followed and I did what they mentioned in [this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72099/how-to-install-a-libreoffice-dictionary-spelling-check-thesaurus) but no result.Can any one know how get them

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Language Support menu in the System menu and add the languages you want to support. After that restart LibreOffice and you will see that the spellchecker for example will give you the option of using the newly installed languages.

You do have to select the correct language at the bottom of Writer (somewhere in the middle) or you can click right on an underlined word and select Spelling & Grammar