# How to set two language spell check in the OS

Tags: language-support, spell-checking

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to know how I can add another spell check.

My default language is English and I would like to have spell check also for Italian. Any suggestion?

I'm referring to the spell check in the OS (i.e., the one presents in Firefox Browser).

Comment: "spell check" what? Libreoffice? See http://askubuntu.com/a/135185/15811

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm referring to the spell check in the OS (i.e., the one presents in Firefox Browser).

Comment: Dont you think that that is important information to add into the question? ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind done!!

Comment: And it looks like those are handled with an add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

Comment: @Rinzwind: Easier to use the Ubuntu packages, since they are present - see Bruni's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the applications you want spellchecking for. For libreoffice install aspell-it and myspell-it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aspell-it myspell-it
```

Myspell is for mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird.