# Does the Spanish dictionary work on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, libreoffice, dictionary

I was wondering if someone has tested dictionaries on Ubuntu 15.10? I have found old posts and installed the Spanish dictionary from [here](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center?getCategories=Dictionary) but it wont let me choose it and I cant correct my documents written in Spanish.

Comment: Searching for "Spanish" at the link you gave, I see two dictionaries.  Which one did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Set up the system wide language settings as explained in the accepted answer here:  [How to install a LibreOffice Dictionary (Spelling Check, Thesaurus...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72099/how-to-install-a-libreoffice-dictionary-spelling-check-thesaurus).

I did this and then went to `Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Writing Aids` and clicked the Edit button for writing aids.  Selecting Spanish (Spain) now shows an entry under Spelling.  It was empty before changing the system wide settings.

Then close the options and create a new paragraph style.  In the Font tab of the paragraph style, change the language to Spanish (Spain).

Now in paragraphs using the new style, it underlines misspelled words in Spanish.  For example if I enter "Hello", it is underlined as misspelled, but if I enter "Hola" it is not.

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 with LO 4.2.

See also: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Selecting_the_Document_Language.

Comment: Yes Jim K is right - in 15.10 you will have to go through 1 level more:
Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Writing aids  !  Lots of check-boxes find the combinations that works best for you

Comment: @KenMollerup, thanks for catching that.  I edited my answer to include `Language Settings`.